# Radio button ignoring space between strings

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, radio-button

I have a radio button that has an array as value like this,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM os";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $row['client'];

    //Radio button code   
    echo "<li><div class = 'list'><a href = 'searchos.php'><div class = 'toggle-btn-grp cssonly'>

<div><form><input type = 'radio' name = 'os' value = " . $row['client'] . " id = 'myRadio1 onchange='showUser(this.value)' >

    <label class='toggle-btn'>" . $row['client'] . "</label></form></div></div><div></a></li>";
}
```

The radio button is working, but for some reason it keeps ignoring the space between the strings in the array. And it only gives me the value of the first string.

When I hard code the a string with space in the value i.e "Production Cost", it gives me the correct output, so the issue must be with the array then, any ideas on how I Could solve this?

Here is the ajax function for getting the value

```
function showUser(str)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getUser.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: use HTML Encoding space &nbsp;

Comment: "// code for IE6, IE5" are already dead. Please don't revive ;)

Comment: value=".$row['client']." is missing single quotes